# Remove space between number and character - PostgreSQL/REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a table with `medication_product_amount` column where there are spaces between numbers and characteres like below:

```
medication_product_amount
1 UN DE 50 ML
20 UN
1 UN DE 600 G
```

What I want is to remove the single space ONLY between numbers and characters, something like this:

```
new_medication_product_amount
1UN DE 50ML
20UN
1UN DE 600G
```

To do this, I am looking for a regular expression to use in the function REGEXP_REPLACE. I tried using the pattern below, indicating to replace the single space after the numbers, but the output remained the same as the input:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(medication_product_amount, '(^[0-9])( )', '\1') as new_medication_product_amount
from medications
```

Can anyone help me come up with the right way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: That `^` symbol in your regex will mean than only singledigit-space sequences at the _beginning_ of the field will be replaced. Try `([0-9]+) ` instead? (no need to put the space inside brackets)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, @ChrisFCarroll. I have incorporated the modification you suggested and the single space was replaced in the output. However,  the numbers are not being shown

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is a little off. First what yours does. `'(^[0-9])( )', '\1')`

- (^[0-9]) Start Capture (field 1) at the beginning of the string for 1 digit
- followed by Start Capture (field 2) for 1 space.
- Replace the string by field1.

The problems and correction:

- What you want to capture does not necessary the first character of the string. So eliminate the anchor `^`.
- What you want to capture may be more that 1 digit in length. So replace [0-9] by [0-9]+. I.E any number of digits.
- Not actually a problem but a space holds no special meaning in a regexp, it is just a space so no need to capture it unless user later. Replace `( )` with just  .
- END of Pattern. But there may be other occurrences. Tell Postgres to continue with the above pattern until end of string. (see [flag 'g'](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)).

Resulting Expression/Query: ([demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kdc5ocET))

```
select regexp_replace(medication_product_posology, '([0-9]+) ', '\1','g') as new_medication_product_posology
from medications;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, @Belayer. I am getting an error with this query: SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "g"

Comment: Just a guess, but are you missing a comma (,). Please post the exact query that gives the error and the complete error message, so it can reproduced. See [mre]. Add this as an update the to your question not as a additional comment.

Comment: You don't need the `+` - it doesn't matter how many digits there are, all you're looking for is a digit followed by a space and **nothing** else - you simply want to remove the space! See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJs6lwNV).

Answer (score 2):

Match "digit space letter", capturing and the digit and letter using `'([0-9]) ([A-Z])'`, then put them back using back references.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(medication_product_amount, '([0-9]) ([A-Z])', '\1\2') as new_medication_product_amount
from medications
```

Comment: Almost - you forgot the `'g'` - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/e_nbJ64Y). But there's a simpler way - see my comment to @Belayer.